# How to obtain the link/URL to the feed of a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, urls, links, feed

What I need to accomplish is to provide a feed link for every item in a custom taxonomy. The function `get_category_feed_link` only works for categories, and I don't see that tags support this either.

How  to obtain the feed for a custom taxonomy item? Does exists something like `get_taxonomy_feed_link(<your_custom_taxonomy_name>, <your_custom_taxonomy_item_id>)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Oops... just found how, [by reading the source](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html):

```
get_term_feed_link( $my_custom_taxonomy_term->term_id, 'my_custom_taxonomy_name' );`
```

It's just not documented in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference).